# Can't deploy basic Rails app on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a very basic Rails app with no database like this:

```
rails new src -O
cd src
rails generate controller Welcome index
```

Locally the app is running fine, but when I run

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

I have this error

```
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
Abort testing: Your Rails environment is running in production mode!
```

I have no clue of what's wrong...

UPDATE:

Finally I changed the line to and it worked:
    bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production --trace assets:precompile

Comment: Does [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6874428) help?

Comment: Thanks, I saw this answer before posting, but I didn't like it. It makes no sense to change files like these for a basic project.